# Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be subspaces of V.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be subspaces of $V$.

> if $W_1 \cap W_2= 0,\dim W_1+ \dim W_2= \dim V$. How to show that $V=W_1 \oplus W_{2}$?

> $\dim(W_1+W_2)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2-\dim(W_1 \cap W_2)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2-\dim(0)=\dim W_1+\dim W_2 =\dim V $

> Can I conclude that $V=W_1+W_2$?

> if so, then $V=W_1+W_2,W_1\cap W_2=0\Rightarrow V=W_1 \oplus W_2?$
> Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know that $\dim W_1+\dim W_2 = \dim V$, applying the rank-nullity law $$\dim (W_1+W_2) + \dim (W_1\cap W_2) = \dim W_1+\dim W_2$$yields$$\dim (W_1+W_2) + \dim (W_1\cap W_2) = \dim V,$$and it follows that $W_1+W_2 = V$ if and only if $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\}$, in which case $V = W_1\oplus W_2$.

But if your assumption is that $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\}$...

Comment: aha, so $dim(W_1\cap W_2)=0\therefore dim(W_1+W_2)=dimV. $ However, do we have $ dim(W_1+W_2)=dimV\Leftrightarrow W_1+W_2=V $?

Comment: Yes, provided the dimension of $V$ is finite. Then the only subspace of $V$ with dimension equal to the one of $V$ is $V$ itself.